# Bone found on uk beach

Tags: species-identification, bone

I found this bone on a uk beach. Looks like a hip or shoulder.

[image: bone I found on beach]It has saw marks in so didnt die of natural causes. Anyone know what its from? Maybe cow or pig

Comment: Please update with more info. [Edit] your post to include dimension measurements, more precise info about the location you found it (e.g., more specific beach, surrounding landscapes/habitats/land use, where on the beach it was found), and also include more photos. This additional info is needed to receive a more accurate answer

Answer (score -2):

It's the right hip joint [from a cow pelvis](https://www.google.com/search?q=horse%20pelvis&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiB7ovV4av7AhUNShoKHVL7DugQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=horse%20pelvis&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeOgQIIxAnUIX6AVj7ggJgwIQCaABwAHgAgAG2AogB-giSAQc0LjIuMS4xmAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=MTRxY8GRCY2UadL2u8AO&bih=620&biw=1366#imgrc=bHGjh4domuDTfM) that has been well worn by the stones on the beach.

A cow is a mammal often used for milk which lives in fields, they have 4 legs and 2 horns and say moo.

Comment: +1 for clarifying cow.